# Wordpress Customizr featured page editing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress and PHP. I am trying to set up my website using Customizr template. I am using xili-language plugin to make it multilingual. Since I am using 2 different languages, I obviously want to display featured pages on front page in different languages. I did read documentation of Customizr template, but I am not familiar to PHP and Wordpress template editing at all... I found this pice of code:

> Hi, you can change the featured pages id with the filter named :
>   tc_fp_id and defined as follow in the core code :

```
  $featured_page_id  = apply_filters( 'tc_fp_id', esc_attr( tc__f( '__get_option' , 'tc_featured_page_'.$fp_single_id) ), $fp_single_id );
```

Could someone please tell me what does this means and where do I implement this? (I assume it has to be added to functions.php file)

Comment: P.S.: URL is http://gniteckm.esy.es/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I am using Customizr 3.3.28.
I was able to switch the slider according to the language by editing the php file:
./inc/parts/class-content-slider.php

```
$slider_name_id               = $this -> tc_get_current_slider( $queried_id );
if ($_GET['lang'] == 'en_us') {                                              
  $slider_name_id = 'activities-slider-en-us';                               
}                                                                            
if ($_GET['lang'] == 'pt_br') {                                              
  $slider_name_id = 'activities-slider-pt-br';                               
}
```

I know it is ugly because the slider name is hard-coded, but unless they can support this natively, I will just have to hack it like that.

I would try a similar approach for the featured pages, but I believe that they should work out of the box with two languages. Still digging...